# smart quotes not converting properly into UTF8

Tags: php, mysql, xml, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a PHP script that imports and parses XML files and saves the data into the database:

- Database collation: `utf8_general_ci`, charset: `utf8`
- Page's charset : `utf-8`
- XML files: `ANSI`, contains smart quotes (from MS Word)

So during import I do a `utf8_encode()` on the text from the XML files prior to saving into the database and subsequently displaying on the page.

But when successfully imported, and saved into DB,

- Database: smart quotes are saved as `?` character (viewed from CMD)
- Page: smart quotes are displayed as boxes

Any ideas as to why the smart quotes are not being converted correctly, even when using `utf8_encode()`?

**EDIT:**

@Tomalak: The XML files are actually `.txt`, no XML declaration (`<?xml ... ?>`), and no root element. My script actually adds a root element just so the parser works:

`utf8_encode('<article>' . file_get_contents($xmlfile) . '</article>');`

Seems like I need to add an XML declaration..? If so, how should it look like?

Comment: Can you post the XML declaration (`<?xml ... ?>`) of your XML files, along with the character code (use a hex editor) the smart quotes have there?

Comment: @Tomalak, I edited my question to answer your comment

Comment: There you have your error. Add an XML declaration `<?xml encoding="Windows-1252"?><article> .  file_get_contents($xmlfile) . </article>` and remove the `utf8_encode()` part. Then parse the resulting string with `DOMDocument`. Just make sure that the `encoding` declaration matches the bytes in the text file. (At least I suppose it should work this way.)

Comment: @Tomalak: if you could rewrite that comment as an answer, I would tick it as the accepted answer :) One question though, how did you know "windows-1252" should be used? Because I tried "iso-8859-1" and it didn't work (I opened the XML (txt) files in Firefox which reported the file as iso-8859-1)

Comment: @Tomalak: also, how come there is no need to convert it to utf8 using utf8_encode, since the database is in utf8?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your XML string (i.e. file contents) is *not* encoded as UTF-8, you need an XML declaration that denotes the file encoding. If an XML declaration is missing, the parser will assume UTF-8.

As long as you do not use "special" characters (i.e. anything outside of the ASCII range), it will work without a declaration even if your file is not *really* UTF-8-encoded. This is because UTF-8 is byte-compatible to ASCII. But as soon as characters are used that are on one of the code pages — like the "smart quotes" — it will break because these are represented by different bytes in UTF-8.

In your case there are text files in a legacy encoding that you wrap with a root element to turn them into well-formed XML. Therefore you need to add the XML declaration yourself:

```
'<?xml encoding="Windows-1252"?><article>'.file_get_contents($xmlfile).'</article>'
```

This way you instruct the `DOMDocument` how to interpret the bytes in your string. I assumed `Windows-1252` for you because you said ANSI and mentioned the curly quotes.

In fact, 95% of the time this is what people really mean, even on Linux and even if they say `ISO-8859-1` (or `latin-1`), which is almost, but not *exactly* the same thing.

To be extra sure you can open your text files in a hex editor, spot a few special characters and compare their byte values with the suspected encoding. For [`Windows-1252`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). For the curly quotes the expected byte values would be:

- `“` 147 (0x93)
- `”` 148 (0x94)

Once the meaning of the individual bytes in your string is declared, `DOMDocument` can make sense of them and does the right thing.

When it comes to in the DB, I strongly suspect there is some automagic encoding conversion going on. I admit that I don't know enough about PHP/mySQL/Unicode integration to say for sure.

Answer (score 1):

They are being converted correctly, because utf8_encode does exactly what it's supposed to be doing and removes them from the input stream.

utf8_encode converts text in ISO-8859-1 into UTF-8 encoding. ISO-8859-1 does not contain the smartquote characters. Your webpage is probably being treated as MSWIN1252 encoding in the browser, which does contain smartquote characters, and you're forcing PHP's input into ISO-8859-1 by calling utf8_encode on it. This means that the only characters that will make it into your database are these ones: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout

To solve this, you have to make sure that the webpage itself is in UTF-8 encoding, and remove all the utf8_encode/utf8_decode statements from your code. This page explains how to properly work with UTF-8: http://malevolent.com/weblog/archive/2007/03/12/unicode-utf8-php-mysql/

Comment: what about latin 1 character at decimal 60 ? isn't that the smart quote character ?

Comment: @bvdb No, that's not a smart quote but a backtick. The smart quote characters are 145 through 148 on the Windows-1252 character set: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Character_set

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the problem is that there are two types of smart quotes.

windows-1252, and latin-1

utf8_encode assumes it's latin-1, so it gets the smart quotes wrong.

if we know the input data is windows-1252, we can use iconv to convert it.

```
$string=iconv ( "Windows-1252" , "UTF-8" , $oldstring );
```

This is the real answer.